# connect with local system mongodb database with other docker container

Tags: mongodb, express, docker, mean-stack

I have developed sample meanstack application (sampledocker). I want to run this application in docker. And I want to connect my system database(**my system ip address:192.168.1.174**) Mongodb database into that docker application.

1. docker build -t nitikishu/sampledocker
2. docker push nitikishu/sampledocker
3. docker pull nitikishu/sampledocker
4. docker run -p 4200:4200 nitikishu/sampledocker

Now Docker container has sampledocker application image. The server page has **mongoose.connect("mongodb://mongo:27017/dbname")**

From this env file I am passing this mongodb path into server.js (app.js)

***My project structure is:***

1. SAMPLE

   - node_modules
   - public

     - controller
     - samplecontroller.js
     - index.html
     - index1.html
   - dockerignore.txt
   - Dockerfile
   - env.Config
   - docker-compose.yml
   - package.json
   - server.js

How to connect mongodb with sampledocker container in docker?
This db I want to connect with sampledocker container.

**Unable to login to the application**

***Dockerfile:***

```
FROM node:latest
RUN mkdir -p C:\Users\user2\Sample
WORKDIR C:\Users\user2\Sample
COPY package.json C:\Users\user2\Sample
RUN npm install
COPY  . .
EXPOSE 4200
CMD [ “npm”, “start” ]
```

***docker-compose.file***

```
version : '3'
services :
  sampledocker:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
    depends_on:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.4.2
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - data:/data/db
volumes:
  data:
```

***server.js(main.js)***

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');
const chalk = require('chalk');
const errorHandler = require('errorhandler');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
const passport = require('passport');
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var app = express();
var multer = require('multer');
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
dotenv.load({ path: '.env.Config' });
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.set('views', __dirname + '\\public');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
mongoose.connect("mongodb://mongo:27017/dbname");
mongoose.connection.on('error', () => 
{
    console.log(error);
    process.exit();
});

app.use(session({
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    store: new MongoStore({
        url:"mongodb://mongo:27017/dbname",
        autoReconnect: true
    })
}));

app.set('port', process.env.App_PORT || 3000);
app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('%s server running on port', chalk.green('✓'), app.get('port'));
    console.log('  Press CTRL-C to stop\n');
});
```

Comment: Hi N15; it's not clear what's wrong, because you haven't shown us how your application is failing. Does it produce an error, for example?

Comment: I am unable to access the application with the application username and password while login. when I hit login button it should connect my system db to verify the username password in the sampledb. if success it should redirect to next page. I am not getting any error. page also not redirecting. is there db connection problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the [.env file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/) to define environment variables for use in the container:

> MONGODB_URI=mongodb://192.168.1.174:27017/Sample_DB
>   SESSION_SECRET=sample
>   App_PORT = 4200

But, that's not how it works. The environment variables in the .env file are *"used for variable substitution in your Compose file"*, not for the *container's* environment.

As the docs go on to say:

> Environment variables defined in the .env file are not automatically visible inside containers. To set container-applicable environment variables, follow the guidelines in the topic [Environment variables in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/), which describes how to pass shell environment variables through to containers, define environment variables in Compose files, and more.

Comment: your right. I used mongo container inside the docker-compose file. mongodb://mongo:27017/dbname. Then also unable to login. I am using windows 8. my docker is running on virtual machine. Is it possible to connect and run the mongodb on windows os